# WPF datepicker : Date from and Date To

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I got two datepicker in my WPF canvas. What i trying to do is like the datepicker from airline website. The first calendar allow user to pick the departure date and the second calendar allow user to pick the return date. Let say i select 11/11/2012 from datapickerA, when i click on the second datepickerB, the dates **before 11/11/2012** are disabled. What should i put in the datepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DisplayDateStart` property of the `DatePicker`.  It is a `DependencyProperty`, so you can supply it via your `DataContext` using MVVM, or by setting `DisplayDateStart` of your second `DatePicker` to `SelectedDate` from the first `DatePicker`:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="Date1"/>
<DatePicker DisplayDateStart="{Binding ElementName=Date1, Path=SelectedDate}"/>
```