# DatePicker Default Date Shown

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DatePicker and when I click into it to select a date, it's defaulted to show Today's Month. Is it possible to change the default month shown without setting the SelectedDate/SelectedValue? I have 2 DatePickers in my user control. I would like the second DatePicker to show 1 month after the first DatePicker.

Example

DatePicker1.SelectedDate = 2017-01-01

When clicking into DatePicker2, the defaulted showing month should be 2017-02-01

Comment: Have you had a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13577045/2029607)?

Comment: @XAMlMAX That is completely different from my question. That is to set the range capabilities of the datepicker, instead of focusing on setting default date shown. A user posted a great solution for question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `DisplayDate` property:

```
dp.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
dp.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);
```